# Configure Ignite logger and appender using java

Tags: ignite

I want to configure the ignite log4j2 configuration programatically instead of xml.
How to configure ignite log4j2 configuration using java? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately built-it `Ignite` [integration](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging#log4j2) doesn't support pure programmatic way of configuration at the moment.

But in fact you're able to use `slf4j` logging facade backed by the `log4j2` under the hood. In this case you'll have some sort of a full power over logging configuration.
In order to achieve that you should add `log4j2` dependencies manually as well as [ignite-slf4j](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging#slf4j) dependency. In the meanwhile you need `log4j2` `slf4j` [binding](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/) to allow `Ignite` logging facilities transfer calls to the `log4j2`.

For instance if you use `maven` then your `pom.xml` should contain:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you'll be able to follow official [insеructions](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) to configure that stuff. For example you can try adding a class that extends `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory` to your classpath. It could look somehow like that:

```java
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.AppenderComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;

@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
public class CustomConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

    static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        builder.setConfigurationName(name);
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
        builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).
            addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").
            addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").
            addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY,
            Filter.Result.NEUTRAL).addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);
        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG).
            add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).
            addAttribute("additivity", false));
        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
        return createConfiguration(name, builder);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[] {"*"};
    }
}
```

It would be possible to make logging customization there.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But ignite should all out of the box to provide logger configuration programatically.

Comment: You're welcome. According the rules & traditions of the community could you please consider accepting the answer in case it has helped you.